# Java's invokeLater() equivalent in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm new to Windows Forms from the Java Swing world. Is there any equivalent for Java's [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread#Executing_code_in_the_EDT)? Or, how can I dispatch a task to be run on the main Windows Forms event thread?

I'm performing a background task using a synchronous API on a separate thread. At the end of the task, I want to re-enable some disabled buttons. But when I attempt to do so, I get an exception (rightly so) because I'm modifying the UI on a non-UI thread.

How can I enqueue that action to run on the main event thread? I haven't found the answer searching both the web and SO, I'm guessing because I'm not asking the question the right way.  Any help is appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can execute a delegate *on* the UI thread using [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) or [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx). An alternative is to use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which wraps all this up nicely - it's handy if you only ever want to do one thing during the processing and one thing on completion, but if you want to perform arbitrary operations on the UI, using `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` is more flexible.

I have a page on using `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` in my [threading tutorial](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml). (It doesn't cover `BackgroundWorker`, I'm afraid.)

You might also want to look at [Joe Albahari's threading tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Apartments_and_Windows).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Erik. I was aware of BackgroundWorker, and I'll be wrapping my currently synchronous API in that eventually. For now, I just wanted to wrap a UI around a command-line tool, so just needed a quick and easy way of executing it on a separate thread.